# Bandwidth Management for VPS w/ Single Interface

Tags: vps, bandwidth-control

I have a VPS that is presented with only one network interface, `ens3` (besides `lo`).

I was thinking I could make a virtual network interface and use the [token bucket filter](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-tbf) queue discipline to limit bandwidth for that particular interface. So I created a `tun0` interface on my Debian 12 test server. (I know `tun0` is often used for OpenVPN, but I don't have that installed.)

```
# ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
# ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun0
# ip link set up dev tun0

# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.1:80
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

# tc qdisc add dev tun0 root tbf rate 4mbit burst 128kbit latency 400ms
```

Here is `tun0` (notice `qdisc tbf`):

```
3: tun0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc tbf state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I bound nginx to 10.0.0.1:80 and confirmed it.

```
# netstat -anpe46
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:80             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14048      831/nginx: master p
```

I ran wget from another computer and expected to only receive 4mbps on my download. Unfortunately, I got full speed.

`nload` shows me a graph of bandwidth usage, but there was none on the `tun0` interface. It did show the network bandwidth only on the `ens3` interface. Why in the world?!?

Furthermore:

```
/sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0/statistics# cat tx_bytes rx_bytes
0
0
```

I have only a single "physical" interface on my VPS which is assigned a public IP address. Any ideas how I might use virtual networking to place limits on bandwidth usage for different services on my VPS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer! Turns out I don't need any virtual interfaces.

`tc` has the ability to filter packets and create rules all on a single interface.

[**This resource**](http://luxik.cdi.cz/%7Edevik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm) was of immense help, and changed my mind from TBF (token bucket filtering) to HTB (hierarchical token bucket). HTB allows different layers of hierarchy and sharing between sibling classes.

So here is a demo that limits port 80 (web server --> internet) to approximately 8 MB/s (`wget` reports 7.34 MB/s in LAN test):

```
tc qdisc add dev enp0s3 root handle 1: htb default 12

tc class add dev enp0s3 parent 1:  classid 1:1  htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev enp0s3 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate    5mbps ceil    8mbps
tc class add dev enp0s3 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps

tc filter add dev enp0s3 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.11.52 match ip sport 80 0xffff flowid 1:10
```

And if you want to delete a class or filter, replace `add` with `del`. You must delete the filter before you can delete the corresponding class or you'll get the error: `RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy`.

For example, here is the correct order to tear everything down:

```
tc filter del dev enp0s3 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.11.52 match ip sport 80 0xffff flowid 1:10

tc class del dev enp0s3 parent 1:  classid 1:1  htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class del dev enp0s3 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate    5mbps ceil    8mbps
tc class del dev enp0s3 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps

tc qdisc del dev enp0s3 root handle 1: htb default 12
```

And you can view your config with these commands (assuming you haven't torn everything down):

```
# show your queue disciplines
tc -d qdisc show

# show your classes
tc -d class show dev enp0s3

# show statistics for your classes
tc -s class show dev enp0s3
```

Other helpful links:

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-htb
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/advanced_traffic_control
- [Way TMI](http://intronetworks.cs.luc.edu/current2/mobile/tokenbucket.html)
- [Filtering Examples](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.filters.html)